# Active Directory set alternative UPN as new default

Tags: active-directory, upn

Is it possible to set an alternative UPN suffix as new default.

We have the problem that our domain have a @domain.local suffix.

I know how to add a new UPN suffix, or change the UPN on a user per GUI or for mass changes per script.

Also i know there is no way to change it globally, but i read somewhere it should be possible to change the default UPN for OU´s them self. This would be fine since we have different subsidiary company's in our AD.

Answer (score 0):

No, the default UPN is the local domain. There is also not a "per-OU" setting, however it is possible to use Active Directory Users and Computers, select multiple accounts, and change the UPN.

More information:

[Set Default UPN Suffix for Creating New Users in Active Directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/45576/set-default-upn-suffix-for-creating-new-users-in-active-directory)

Comment: For that i have already a script: